# Linear bijection non-preserving Hausdorff propery

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces

My question is:
If $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous and linear bijection between topological vector spaces, is it possible that $X$ is Hausdorff and $Y$ is non-Hausdorff? (TVSs are considered in the more general sense here -- they need not be Hausdorff.)

Comment: put on $X$ the discrete topology: every map from $X$ to anywhere is continuous. Put on $X$ the trival topology: every surgective map from anywhere to $X$ is continuous. Not take the identity from $(X,disc)$ to $(X,triv)$. $(X,disc)$ is clearly hausdordd and $(X,triv)$ is clearly non hausdorf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(X,\tau )$ be any Hausdorff topological vector space , and let $\sigma =\{\emptyset , X\}$ be a trivial topology on $X.$ Then the identity $\mbox{id}_X :(X,\tau )\to (X ,\sigma )$ is a continuous and linear bijection but $(X,\sigma )$ is not  Hausdorff topological vector space.

Comment: $(X,\sigma)$ should not be the vector space of dimension $0$ then :-)

Comment: Actually, I meant a bit more specific situation. But FisiaiLusie thank you very much! Y is demanded to be a quotient A/B of norm spaces A and B, besides that we still demand the non-Hausdorff property. [Thus trivially, B not closed in A. On the quotient the quotient topology is considered. The norm on B coincides with the restriction of the norm on A -- inherited topology.]